Как закрыть доступ к сайту WP?
Взломали сайт. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как закрыть доступ к сайту всем кроме себя??

<RequireAll>
Require all denied
Require not ip <Твой IP>
</RequireAll>

ps: Это верно для соединений http(s). Если ваш сервер позволяет подключение по другим протоколам, например telnet, эта запись в .htaccess мало чем будет полезна.

Как-то так
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <Твой IP>

Если на этом хостинг-аккаунте сайты не изолированы и  есть другие сайты, то их тоже нужно закрыть до полного лечения ВСЕХ сайтов.
См также Вирусы в wordpress

это в .htaccess добавить?

@АндрейКурусь Ну да. Ты же эту метку поставил.

@SeVlad order ведь deprecated

@АндрейКурусь https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order

у хостинг провайдера прокансультируйтесь, можно ограничить доступ по IP.
Если в докере сайт то сделайте на внутреннем IP и работайте через VPN или SSH,
вот инструкция:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJAGiKZsRiQ

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.
